# Spring Boot Microservice JUnit Test - How to write a test method with adding the option of @PreAuthorize

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-security

I just want to add a `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")` and `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')")` in the methods of order controller and I also revise the controller test method after I define a login method in auth service in terms of User and Admin role.

After I add `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')")` of placeOrder method of controller, I revise its test method.

Here is the method of order controller

```
 @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')")
 @PostMapping("/placeorder")
    public ResponseEntity<Long> placeOrder(@RequestBody OrderRequest orderRequest) {

        log.info("OrderController | placeOrder is called");

        log.info("OrderController | placeOrder | orderRequest: {}", orderRequest.toString());

        long orderId = orderService.placeOrder(orderRequest);
        log.info("Order Id: {}", orderId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(orderId, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Here is the example test method in ordercontrollertest in order service.

```
@Test
    @DisplayName("Place Order -- Success Scenario")
    void test_When_placeOrder_DoPayment_Success() throws Exception {

        OrderRequest orderRequest = getMockOrderRequest();
        String jwt = getJWTTokenForRoleUser();

        MvcResult mvcResult
                = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/order/placeorder")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwt)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(orderRequest)))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andReturn();

        String orderId = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();

        Optional<Order> order = orderRepository.findById(Long.valueOf(orderId));
        assertTrue(order.isPresent());

        Order o = order.get();
        assertEquals(Long.parseLong(orderId), o.getId());
        assertEquals("PLACED", o.getOrderStatus());
        assertEquals(orderRequest.getTotalAmount(), o.getAmount());
        assertEquals(orderRequest.getQuantity(), o.getQuantity());
    }
```

Here are the dependenices of order service regarding it.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

How can I define the ROLE in this test method. I tried to use `@WithMockUser(roles="USER")` and `@WithMockUser(roles="ADMIN")` but it didn't help me. (I got 403 Forbidden error.)

Edited ( I also tried to WebSecurityConfig in the service but it didn't help me fix the issue. That's why I removed it from the service.)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests(
                        authorizeRequest -> authorizeRequest
                                .anyRequest()
                                .authenticated());

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Here is the example link : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/microservicecoursedailybuffer)

Here is the test controller : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/microservicecoursedailybuffer/blob/main/orderservice/src/test/java/com/microservice/orderservice/controller/OrderControllerTest.java)

To run the app,
1 ) Run Service Registery (Eureka Server)

2 ) Run config server

3 ) Run zipkin and redis through these commands shown below on docker
docker run -d -p 9411:9411 openzipkin/zipkin
docker run -d --name redis -p 6379:6379 redis

4 ) Run api gateway

5 ) Run other services

Answer (score 1):

I might seem rude, but I'm tired to give you the solution to your problem (it's the 3rd time already, and we would have both saved a lot of time if you had tried it the first time)

## **FOLLOW THOSE TUTORIALS: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials**

It will teach you how to (you obviously don't know how to correctly do it):

- configure your OAuth2 resource-servers
- secure Spring @Components (@Controllers but also @Service and @Repository)
- write unit tests for those components with mocked identities
- write integration test for each micro-service with mocked identities

`@WithMockUser` populates test security context with `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` which is not adapted to OAuth2 resource-servers.

Just follow the [first 3 tutoriuals](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) (for real: write the code and run the tests) and then refer to the [sample](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples) best matching your particular use-case. It should take you less than an hour.

Stop trying to build JWTs to set it as request header when working with MockMvc. Use either `org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.jwt` from `spring-security-test` or `@WithMockJwtAuth` from `spring-addons-oauth2-test`.

Comment: I don't want to use any other dependency, I have a problem in writing a JUnit Controller tests of Spring Boot Microservices.

Comment: This statement proves you have not gone through the first tutorial. Don't worry, I'll carefully avoid any of your further question.

Comment: My example is related with microservice. I tried to get jwt from jwtutils in OrderServiceController. After I added spring-security to add Preauthorize to some methods of controller, I get 403 error. I also defined security chain filter but it didn't help me fix the issue.

Comment: Your case is desperate. I am the author  of the `jwt()` MockMvc post-processor you are trying to use. Do you really intend to explain me how it works, when to use it or how to use it?

Comment: I still couldn't fix the issue. Can you help me? How can I revise security option between api gateway and order service?

Comment: No, I can't help you: you don't explain you problems clearly enough and don't read the answers

Comment: I mentioned what the issue is. I cannot run any test method in controller test with the usage of jwt and role.

Comment: Let's try the kids approach: list the differences between the two pictures (the first tutorial in the answer and each of your micro-services). Hint: get a closer look at security conf, controllers annotations and controller tests.

Answer (score 0):

Add this configuration to test class :

`@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)`

Comment: When I added it to the test class, I got this issue. `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The @PropertyMapping annotation @AutoConfigureMockMvc cannot be used in combination with the @Component annotation @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`